# switch case in where clause of linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

how i can use switch case in where clause as well as select statement can anyone give me examples...

Comment: What do you mean by "select statement"? Do you want to use a subselect in the where clause or do you want a switch statement in the select part?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not use `switch`, you need a construct that returns a value (switch does not return a value in c#), like the [ternary operator `<cond> ? <trueValue> : <falseValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

You can nest them, it will be a bit messy, but should work.

```
cond1 ? valueFor1 :
       (cond2 ? valueFor2 : 
               (cond3 ? valueFor3 : 
                        defaultValue))
```

but in the where-clause it is usually simpler to combine your conditions with `&&` and `||`.